# XCode Cloud Running Out Of Space - Says NSLocalizedDescription=Copy failed

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, cicd, xcode-cloud

Hoping someone else has insight on this, or at the very least it will help others out -

When building our app using XCode Cloud runner on appstoreconnect.apple.com, it fails with a very in-descriptive error of `NSLocalizedDescription=Copy failed`. Checking the logs with Xcode natively shows the following trace:

```
copying file ./PkgInfo ...
ditto: /private/var/folders/dc/qnb7gt0x1gd_9t395xtb1bdr0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~NtuEip/Root/Payload/redacted.app/PkgInfo: No space left on device
2022-03-28 20:23:45 +0000 [MT] /usr/bin/ditto exited with 1
2022-03-28 20:23:45 +0000  copying file ./AppIcon76x76~ipad.png ...
ditto: /private/var/folders/dc/qnb7gt0x1gd_9t395xtb1bdr0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~NtuEip/Root/Payload/redacted.app/AppIcon76x76~ipad.png: No space left on device
2022-03-28 20:23:45 +0000 [MT] Step "<IDEDistributionCopyItemStep: 0x6000009757d0>" failed for distribution item "redacted.app" with error "Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "Copy failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Copy failed}"
```

Suggesting the runner is out of space. The xcodeproj and relevant files are only around 3GB, so it's confusing how this would happen.

While it's possible to do the build on Github Actions, it would be great to do it on Xcode Cloud. I contacted Apple Support on the issue, but received no replies.

Does anyone know how to increase the size of the runner, reduce the size of your app while building, or otherwise solve this issue by different means?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For me the issue was that my mac storage is almost full, When I cleared some storage it worked fine.

Hope this will be helpful to you.